# Identity Hash Code for short lower-case strings

Tags: hash

1) I am going to be receiving sets of unique user ids, with between 1 and 300 entries in each set.

2) Each unique user id is 6-10 characters long, and all lower case a-z ASCII

3) I need to generate a unique identifier for each set, max length 256 characters in the space

4) That unique identifier has, AFAIK, no bounds beyond "valid ASCII".

5) If two different sets generate the same unique group id, people in two unrelated groups will be able to see each others' information and I get to explain to Compliance why I thought that was a good idea. Let's call this the hashcode problem

6) If two identical sets don't produce the same id, a bunch of information will suddenly vanish for those users, and I will get to explain to Business why I thought that was a good idea. Let's call this the random guid problem.

---

Is there an identity hash that will meet my needs? Something like SHA-256 seems like it would be "safe enough", but it feels like the limited input space and the fact that there's no problem with the hash being reversible (compression not cryptography), would mean there's a compression function that could do the job.

Comment: Compression is not guaranteed to actually work -- if the IDs are unique it is in fact quite likely your data is incompressible, or at least will not compress with a sufficiently high factor to always fit. A crypto hash does sound like your best bet, even if collisions are still technically unavoidable -- SHA-2 can go up to 512 bits, which still fits in your output and is more than enough to reduce the chance of a collision to essentially zero for practical purposes. Limited input space is not a problem; crypto hashes are designed to make every bit matter.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert : Isn't your post an answer, not a comment?